# How to do count without button

Tags: vb.net

I'm planning to do counting without `Click Event` and if I delete numbers from my textbox my "total will back to zero or nothing"

here's my code for now I'm using button:

```
Private Sub Hitung_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles Hitung.Click
    txtTotal.Text = Val(txtgaji.Text) + Val(txtbonus.Text) + val(txttunjangan.Text) 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no counting there. That's called addition. You need to handle some event in order to execute code but it doesn't have to be the `Click` of a `Button`. If what you're adding is the contents of three `TextBoxes` then you could handle the `TextChanged` event of each of those `TextBoxes`.

Comment: When do you want your increase to happen?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using the `NumericUpDown` controls instead of `TextBoxes` though. They are designed for numeric input.  You'd then handle the `ValueChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `TextBox1_KeyPress`, `TextBox1_KeyDown` or `TextBox1_KeyUp` to trigger a re-evaluation of the contents of the `TextBox` (Which I have called `TextBox1` in this instance) or your total.  `TextBox1_Change` may also be relevant.

From what I understand of your question, if `len(TextBox1.Text) = 0`, you want to set your summing variable or total to 0 (`txtTotal.Text ="0"`).